# Why do Voice Search isn't shown on my toolbar search action view?

Tags: android

I learn how to add search view on action bar (I use toolbar) from http:/developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html. I can add that feature just fine, but when I want to add voice search, mic icon isn't shown. It looks like I just need to add `android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"`.

I also have some another questions.

1. I set `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);` but why do it still iconified by default?
2. How do I make the content view back to icon when I focus on another widget?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUk3T.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cFnV.png

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```html
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.query);
            textView.setText(query);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/query"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**searchable.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.hint));

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

}
```

Comment: it didn't make any difference